# problem with Jquery LIVE with $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, live

I have a problem, I'm using `.live()` to bind `mouseenter` like this:

```
$('a').live('mouseenter',function(e){
  alert($(this).attr('title'));
});
```

For all my links I get an alert for the first link's title, I think the problem is from `$(this)` but I'm not sure, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the code you posted is what's *actually* running, it works :)  You can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/YyMDg/

See what the difference is in your *actual* code, are you looping somewhere for example, and `$(this)` isn't being evaluated in the handler but somewhere outside of it?